# django retrieving a form's value before POST

Tags: django, django-forms

I know that you can retrieve data from a form using `variable = request.POST.get('FieldName', ''`), but this only works if the data has been posted. However, I'm trying to write code that will retrieve data from a form field that has not been saved or validated yet. Is there a way I can do that?

Comment: As in, you want something real time?

Comment: Do you want to grab the data before or after the POST has been made?

Comment: @Games Brainiac yes, I want real time.

Comment: @limelights, before POST.